# Visual Studio 2012 shell extension development

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating an isolated shell extension and I was just wondering if it would be better to learn c++ for this type of development? I have experience with c# and WPF and I am currently under the impression that I could create the shell by just using the default shell extension and then create the functionality I want using C# and WPF by just creating extensions inside of the shell pack as additional projects in the solution.

If anyone has and tips to offer and any documentation (which is not much from what I have been browsing) that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [Vintage Studio](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/05/12/introducing-vintage-studio/) extension some time ago It allows creating apps for 8-bit vintage computers (e.c. Commodore 64 or 8-bit Atari) using Visual Studio. It contains of 2 dlls - one is just an extension to the editor (syntax coloring, formatting etc) while the other one is a project system that integrates with VS and allows to build the project using 6502 assembly compiler, run the program in an emulator etc. Both dlls were created with C# and the MPFProj. Once I finished the project I tried to make it work in isolated shell. It took me a couple of hours to figure out how to make it work but I came up with the right registry settings and entries in the pkgdef file it worked fine. AFAIR I used [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb685692%28en-us%29.aspx) to learn more about registering an extension as an isolated shell extension. This means that it is possible to create an isolated shell extension just in C#. 
The [blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/05/12/introducing-vintage-studio/) contains a link to my github where you can find source code for the Vintage Studio and some tips (in the Readme file) on setting up and using MPFProj (for instance I found a bug I needed to fix directly in their code).

Comment: Thanks @Pawel that techNet library link is something i didnt know i was looking for